# In Java, a currying function is thread-safe or not

Tags: java, multithreading, function, thread-safety, currying

As far as I understand, a simple java.util.Function should be thread-safe since it takes one parameter, processes it, and returns something. However, what about a currying function?

Let's consider a scenario where I define a private function (which is currying and complex) in a service singleton. Any request handled would call the currying function on its thread:

```
private Function<String, Function<String, Function<LocalDate, Function<LocalDate, Function<String, Function<Integer, Map<String, Object>>>>>>> curryingFunc = id -> path -> startDate -> endDate -> sortKey -> sortOrder -> {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("id", id);
    map.put("path", path);
    map.put("startDate", startDate);
    map.put("endDate", endDate);
    map.put("sortKey", sortKey);
    map.put("sortOrder", sortOrder);
    return map;
};
```

Is it possible that a request on thread-1 just finished setting the id as 'apple' in the map and is about to return the map, but somehow a request on thread-2 just called the function and set the id to 'broccoli', thus causing a race condition problem?

In another scenario, what if it's not taking parameters and composing them as a map but calling some other function? For example:

```
private Function<String, Function<String, Function<LocalDate, Function<LocalDate, Function<String, Function<Integer, UserData>>>>>> curryingFunc = id -> path -> startDate -> endDate -> sortKey -> sortOrder -> {
    return userDataRepository.find(id, path, startDate, endDate, sortKey, sortOrder);
};
```

Comment: A new `Map` is created each time the function is called, so the invocation of the function is thread safe. In your second example, if `find` is thread safe your function is thread safe.

Comment: The reference `map` exists on the stack of a particular `Thread`. So no other `Thread` can see it until the function returns. After the function returns, the caller may do something with `map` which makes it visible to other threads.

Comment: "a simple `java.util.Function` should be thread-safe:" only if it doesn't alter any external state.

Comment: “…a simple java.util.Function should be thread-safe since it takes one parameter, processes it, and returns something.”  **Not correct.** Your particular function is thread-safe because its inputs are immutable.  A Function most certainly is not guaranteed to be thread-safe just because it’s a Function.